# Why did I get a different result-plot between the two solutions?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, comsol

[image: comparison]
>
Hi,

I'm using a sample problem to learn the comsol.
I would like to let my case problem (left) 
3D plot, be the same as the tutorial plot (right).
My problem is that, instead of the right figure plot (that shows the resin-red color traveling from the left edge to the right one), I'm getting the nonconforming left one.
Do you have an idea if there is a choice of getting the right plot, or an advice about why I get the left plot instead of the right?

Thank you in advance!

Panos Deemac

Comment: Looking at your plot, it seems that the figure on the Right is strictly Binary, so the results plotted were only 1 and 0s, thus the Blue vs Red is shown; for Your plot on the left, you have decimals between 0 and 1, I wonder if you are suppose to apply a Hard decision/Threshhold (i.e. if value>= some threshold then value =1 else 0) to force it to become 1 or 0 - but without more information on your problem, we cannot help further..

Comment: just because of my curiosity: if it's Comsol, why you set tags `Solidworks` and `matlab`?

Comment: I thought that researchers who use comsol would also be interesting in matlab and Solidworks. In other words I would like to maximize my answer amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the Colorbar. In the left the color goes up to 1x10^5 while in the right it goes to 1, thus drawing as red everything above 1. Change the color limits to the same, and you'll get the same plot.